# On projection operators for irreducible representations of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetry, projection

Physicist here, posting here because it seems more appropriate.

I will try to pose this question in the most general way possible, so that it is applicable to the most broad number of situations. If it is at all relevant for the answer keep in mind that this question arises from the study of the rotational symmetry of quantum operators on a lattice.

I have a system with a symmetry described by a finite group $G$ of order $n_G$. (the point group in question is the cubic group $O$ of order 24 (it is isomorphic to $S_4$)).
I have a set of objects (operators) $\{\hat{O}_i\}$ spanning a vector space of operators, we will call $H = \text{Span}\{\hat{O}_i\}$.
I have already managed by hand to build the **reducible** representation $\mathcal{R}$ acting on the $\{\hat{O}_i\}$ basis. I already know ho to compute the Kronecker decomposition of $\mathcal{R}$ by calculating the multiplicities of each irreducible representation of the group using the character tables.
I need to find linear combinations of these $\{\hat{O}_i\}$:
$$
\overline{O}^\mu_a = \sum_i c^\mu_{a,i}\hat{O}_i
$$
Such that $\overline{O}^\mu_a$ transforms according to an irreducible representation of the point group symmetry. In particular, if $\Gamma^\mu$ is the $\mu$-th irreducible representation of the finite group then for every fixed $\mu$ the set $\{\overline{O}^\mu_a \text{ with } a= 1, ..., \dim \Gamma^\mu\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the invariant subspace of $H$ that tranforms according to the $\Gamma^\mu$ representation.
In literature I have found that we can do this using projection operators and both the objects:
$$
\frac{\dim \Gamma^\mu}{n_G}\sum_{g\in G} {\Gamma^\mu}(g)^\dagger_{ab} \mathcal{R}(g)_{ij}\hat{O}_j \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \sum_{g \in G} \chi^\mu(g)^*\mathcal{R}(g)_{ij}\hat{O}_i
$$
should transform according to the $\Gamma^\mu$ representation because of the great orthogonality theorem. The difference in the two approaches is essentially that the first projector is also able to extract an orthonormal basis of the $\Gamma^\mu$ subspace of $H$.

My question is the following, if the Kronecker decomposition of $H$ has different copies of any irreducible representation, i.e. if we have that:
$$
\mathcal{R} = \bigoplus_\mu a_\mu \Gamma^\mu
$$
where there exist $\nu$ such that $a_\nu \geq 2$. Then on which of the subspaces am I projecting? If there are multiple copies of the $\Gamma^\nu$ irreducible representation, and I wish to build an orthonormal basis for each separate invariant subspace tranforming according to $\Gamma^\nu$ then how should I interpret the action of the projection operators? (The first one in particular since I am looking to build the linear combinations explicitly so that would seem more appropriate).

I hope the question is undestandable, but I remain available to provide any clarification if necessary.
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Can you describe your "projection operators" in a coordinatefree way? The indices are really throwing me off. Like, is $\Gamma^\mu(g)_{ab}^\dagger$ the $ab$th entry of the matrix $\Gamma^\mu(g)^\dagger$? In the left formula, is the Einstein summation convention used for the index $j$, so the ${\cal R}(g)$s aren't actually applied to the ${\cal O}_i$s? If there are three "free" indices $a,b,i$ on the left, then in what sense is it even an "operator"? Or is the LHS the *result* of applying the operator to $\hat O_i$, not the operator itself? I am very confused.

Comment: The formulas remind me of [isotypical projectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Decompositions). I think this question really highlights the language barrier between math and physics when it comes to rep thry. Like, what does "Kronecker decomposition" mean? From context, it sounds like it just means writing as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations, or of isotypic components. I have a feeling that understanding what you're even asking will be far harder than actually answering your question.

Comment: @runway44 the coordinates on the $\mathcal{R}\hat{O}$ side are not necessary, it's just the $\mathcal{R}$ representation applied whatever operator you want to project, I chose the basis operators because that's what I am interested in.

Comment: @runway44

On the $\Gamma^\mu$ indexes are needed because, from what I understood from Wigner, that whole object should transform according to the desired irreducible representation for whichever $a$ or $b$ fixed.The entries of the $\Gamma^\mu$ matrices will become the coefficients that linearly combine all the possible rotations of the operator $\hat{O}$ into an operator that transforms according to $\Gamma^\mu$.

Comment: @runway44  you are right Kronecker decomposition is the direct sun decomposition of a reducible representation, i thought it was quite a universal name but here I stand corrected, sometimes it's hard to  even realize the language barrier is there.

Comment: I still don't understand the left formula. How is it a "projection operator" if it turns an element of $H$ into something that's not in $H$?

Answer (score 2):

As I am not trained in physics, I don't quite understand your notation, but I think I understand enough to guess what you're asking for. I am only able to answer in a notation typical in mathematics, though.

Let $(V,\rho)$ be a representation of a finite group. Then we have a decomposition $$V=\bigoplus_i V_i^{n_i}$$ where $V_i$ runs over all (pairwise non-isomorphic) irreducible representations. (I guess this is what you call the Kronecker decomposition)
Now if $V_i$ is an irreducible representation with character $\chi_i$, then we have the isotypical projection operator
$$P_i:v \mapsto \frac{\mathrm{dim}V_i}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\overline{\chi(g)}\rho(g)v$$
What this operator does is that it is a $G$-equivariant projection from $V$ onto $V_i^{n_i}$, the latter is called the $V_i$-isotypical component of $V$.
If $n_i \geq 2$, then the image of this projection operator is not irreducible, but it is a direct sum of copies of the same irreducible representation.

Depending on what you mean by the phrase "to transform according to the irreducible representation $V_i$", it may or may not be true that the image of the projection operator does this:

- If you mean that the image of $P_i$ is isomorphic to $V_i$ as a representation, then this is generally not true.
- If you mean that the image of $P_i$ can be decomposed into representations isomorphic to $V_i$, then it is true.

In the latter case, the image of $P_i$ is the maximal subspace that "transforms according to $V_i$".

Comment: ok i believe your answer covers my question like 99% of the way through. The 1% that is left is, adopting your notation, the following:

Once i Projected on $P_i$ is there a way to constructively decompose $P_i$ into the $n_i$ copies of the $\rho_i$ representation? By constructively i mean i would like to explicitly build the linear combinations that describe orthonormal bases of the the $n_i$ invariant subspaces of dimension $\dim \rho_i$ that should be found in $P_i$

Comment: thank you very much. Just to give some references to understand where my argument comes from, it mainly comes from Wigner's "Group theory and its application to atomic spectra" to be precise chapter 12 called "The Algebra of representation theory"

Comment: @Defcon97 one thing to keep in mind is that in general there are not "the" $n_i$ copies of $\rho_i$, although the notation $V_i^{n_i}$ seems to suggest otherwise. For example, if we look at the trivial representation (so that everything just reduces to linear algebra), there are more than two one-dimensional subspaces inside $\Bbb C^2$. A similar phenomenon occurs with nontrivial representations.

Comment: hmm I am not sure I understood your argument, but i'll make mine more general to see if we can circumvent this problem. I was building from your phrare "the image of $P_i$ can be decomposed into representations isomorphic to $V_i$."
So there has to be a non singular matrix that, when used as a change of basis matrix on the Im$P_i$ space should put it in a block diagonal form where each block is an element of the $\rho_i$ representation, and there should be $n_i$ of these blocks.

This is what i undestand when i read that it can be dcomposed, am i right?
If so, can i separate the blocks?

Comment: @Defcon97 yes, that's correct. I'm just saying there might be multiple such matrices.

Comment: Of course but different change of basis matrix shouldn't just give us the same block diagonal forms but with irreducible representations that are different but all equivalent to $\rho_i$? For the sake of finding a unique solution let's say that i have picked the explicit form of all the irreducible representations of the group that i want to find in my block diagonal form and i want my "block reduced" representation to have on the diagonal exactly that representation and not an equivalent one.

With this constraint is it possible to find a unique basis change matrix ?

Comment: @Defcon97 Suppose that the group $G$ is the trivial group acting on a $2$-dimensional space $V$. The action will always be the identity matrix, and every non-singular matrix can be a basis change matrix. In general, as soon as you have two copies of a given irreducible representation, there are infinitely many change of basis matrices that will work, even of determinant 1. In other words, the *centralizer*, the set of matrices that don't change the representation at all by change of basis, is infinite.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yes i understand what you are saying but I don't feel like this should be the end of the story. If there are two distinct copies of that irreducible representation at least there should be, inside Im$P_i$ two  invariant subspaces. Why isn't it possible to extract these two subspaces explicitly and find an orthonormal basis for each?

Comment: @Defcon97 Because there are infinitely many such invariant subspaces. In a sum of two copies of an irreducible rep, say thought of as $x$ and $y$ axes, there are infinitely many diagonal copies. A CoB matrix can fix the $x$ axis and swing one of those diagonals into the $y$ co-ordinate. A choice of basis privileges two copies of the irreducible from the sea of possibilities, but any pair of subspaces will work. There is no 'standard' or 'canonical' pair of subspaces to choose, so no formula can give you one. It's like choosing an $x$ and $y$ axis on a circular piece of paper.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven hmm you kind of convinced me honestly. But if I can ask a subsequent small question, why is it then that this doesn't happen in Lie Theory too? For continuous groups when a representation contains two copies of an irreps it is possible to separate these two copies and associate different vectors to them (it's what we did with hadrons). What is it in finite groups that breaks this reasoning?

Comment: @Defcon97 I see no reason why Lie groups are different. Indeed, the trivial representation is a perfectly good representation of a Lie group. My guess is that your physical theory had some hidden co-ordinate system that allowed you to do this. For example, you had one copy then used an inner product, or norm, or something, that allowed you to find another. Like fixing an $x$-axis then using orthogonality to find the $y$-axis. It's unique! you cry, but only because you have fixed your definition of the distance function beforehand.

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that this issue doesn't just occur for the trivial representation, but for every irreducible representation as soon as there is more than one copy of it contained in the representation.

Comment: If you have a particular representation, then you can still find a basis of the kind you're after, but this basis will not be unique, it will involve non-canonical choices and there is no formula that expresses such a basis in a way that works uniformly for all representations.

Comment: @Defcon97 Re: *"Why isn't it possible to extract these two subspaces ...?"* It is possible. But the two subspaces are not uniquely determined, and you will have to make arbitrary choices to do this. Which is just like the situation in linear algebra: if you have a 2D vector space, then it's possible to find two orthogonal 1D subspaces it's a direct sum of, and to do this you use Gram-Schmidt on a random pair of vectors (so long as they aren't linearly dependent). You can do the same for reps essentially, but you have to continually take $G$-orbits along the way.